# generic binary search tree

Tags: generics, c++-cli, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a binary search tree console application, specifically, a method to list the shortest path between two target nodes.  My approach is to

1) Create an ArrayList of the values of each target node in the tree from the root node to the target (one ArrayList for each path)
2) Compare the two ArrayLists, removing all duplicates except the last one (which would represent where the two paths branch
3) combine the two remaining ArrayLists into a single array and print to console with a for loop

This is the method I'm working with.  The problem I'm having is that I'm never entering the block that reads "if (list1[n] == list2[n])", even though the ArrayLists are printing out with the values
Contents of _pathArrayList1:  5, 7, 9
Contents of _pathArrayList2:  5, 7, 9, 10, 12, 11

I tried typcasting, but that didn't help.

```
array<T>^ removeDuplicates(ArrayList^ list1, ArrayList^ list2)
{
    int forLoopCount;
    int i; // for loop iterator for this method
    Console::WriteLine(L"Contents of _pathArrayList1: ");
    for (i = 0; i < list1->Count; i++)
        Console::WriteLine(list1[i]);

    Console::WriteLine(L"Contents of _pathArrayList2"); 
    for (i = 0; i < list2->Count; i++)
        Console::WriteLine(list2[i]);

    // find out which array is the shortest; we need to use the shorter of the two
    if (list1->Count - list2->Count < 0)
        forLoopCount = list1->Count;
    else
        forLoopCount = list2->Count;
    Console::WriteLine("Value of forLoopCopunt is " + forLoopCount);
    array<T>^ combineArray = gcnew array<T>(forLoopCount);

    for (int n = 0; n < forLoopCount; n++)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(L"List1[n] = " + list1[n]);
        Console::WriteLine(L"list2[n] = " + list2[n]);

        if (list1[n] == list2[n])  // never entering this block of code
        {
            if (list2[n+1] == list1[n+1])
            {
                Console::WriteLine(L"Removing " + list1[n] + " and " + list2[n]);
                list1->RemoveAt(n);
                list2->RemoveAt(n);
                n --;
            }
            else
            {
                Console::WriteLine(L"Deleting " + list1[n]);
                list1->RemoveAt(n);
                //_pathArrayList1->Reverse();
                return combineArray = combineArrays(_pathArrayList1, _pathArrayList2);
            }
        }
    }
    return combineArray = combineArrays(_pathArrayList1, _pathArrayList2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify "I tried typcasting, but that didn't help.".

`ArrayList` does not use generics, so it deals with everything as Objects. Even if the two objects are ints, when they're typed as Object, `==` won't compare the integer values as you expect.

```
Object^ o1 = 1;
Object^ o2 = 1;

bool asObject = (o1 == o2); // false
bool asInt = ((int)o1 == (int)o2); // true
```

If you switch out your `ArrayList` for `List<int>`, then `==` will work as you expect, with the added benefits of type-safety.

Other Notes:

- Use [Math.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5sbzt2y.aspx) when setting `forLoopCount`. If other people have to stop and think about it to figure out if the code is correct, for something that simple, use the function.
- Before checking if `list2[n+1] == list1[n+1]`, make sure there's an extra item in both lists. In your example data (5-7-9 and 5-7-9-10-12-11), this will give you an exception when `list1[n]` is the 9.
- You can remove `gcnew array<T>(forLoopCount)`, or even `combineArray` entirely. That object is getting thrown away when you assign the return value of combineArrays.

---

### Edit

If the objects in the passed lists are the items themselves (not their node addresses, or something else that's always an `int`), then I'd recommend adding `where T : IEquatable<T>` to the generic definition. That gives you an [Equals(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) method, and you can use that instead of `==`, which isn't defined for all types. (If you implement this on your types, just be sure to implement all three methods Equals(T), Equals(object), and GetHashCode(), so that everything's consistent.)

To help with building the search tree in the first place, you may find [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) useful. Use the CompareTo method instead of the comparison operators (e.g., `<`).

Comment: Thanks David, that does in fact fix my problem.  By "typecasting", I meant that I tried "if ((T)list1[n] == (T)list2[n]{}"  I'm not sure though, how this approach can be used in a generic environment, where other objects may be used (like strings, records, etc.).  Am I missing a bigger picture?